# How to generate a sample of artificial data with a particular variance?

Tags: r, dataset, mean, variance

I am trying to generate a data set with the following information->
sample size:200
variance = 2
mean = 20
I have tried generating it using the rnorm() function but it only takes standard deviation as variable. I have also tried to square root the standard deviation to generate the desired variance but it doesn't work either.
How can I generate such dataset with that mean and variance in Rstudio?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
x = rnorm(200, 20, sd=sqrt(2))

c(mean(x), var(x))

[1] 20.064919  1.981597
```